# haproxy pgsql-check and eof message

Tags: haproxy, pgbouncer

I am using haproxy 1.5.4 . in front of pgbouncer .

my configuration has pgsql-check enabled . Once the check is enabled i see these messages in **pgbouncer log** .

```
2015-10-01 05:02:46.203 27104 LOG C-0x6609d0: (nodb)/(nouser)@10.53.6.132:38711 closing because: client unexpected eof (age=8)
2015-10-01 05:02:58.205 27104 LOG C-0x6609d0: (nodb)/(nouser)@10.53.6.132:39111 closing because: client unexpected eof (age=8)
2015-10-01 05:03:10.207 27104 LOG C-0x6609d0: (nodb)/(nouser)@10.53.6.132:39707 closing because: client unexpected eof (age=9)
2015-10-01 05:03:22.208 27104 LOG C-0x6609d0: (nodb)/(nouser)@10.53.6.132:40281 closing because: client unexpected eof (age=8)
```

These were the same messages i was getting when the default check was there . I mean when there was no 
option pgsql-check.

I have also tried providing a valid user in the pgsql-check and still i see the eof message like this .

option pgsql-check user pg

```
2015-10-01 04:58:27.057 27104 LOG C-0x6609d0: pg/pg@10.53.6.132:17813 login attempt: db=pg user=pg
2015-10-01 04:58:27.057 27104 LOG C-0x6609d0: pg/pg@10.53.6.132:17813 closing because: client unexpected eof (age=0)
2015-10-01 04:58:29.058 27104 LOG C-0x6609d0: pg/pg@10.53.6.132:17882 login attempt: db=pg user=pg
2015-10-01 04:58:29.058 27104 LOG C-0x6609d0: pg/pg@10.53.6.132:17882 closing because: client unexpected eof (age=0)
```

My question is how different is `pgsql-check` from the the default `tcp check` . I was under impression that it will close the connection properly and i will not be seeing these message in the log .

Are we seeing these messages even with `pgsql-check` ?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same kind of messages when HAProxy is connecting directly to PostgreSQL (in my case postgres 9.4 and HAProxy 1.5).

Without giving any username I get:

```
LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
LOG:  incomplete startup packet
```

With a valid username:

```
LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
```

So, apparently, pgsql-check without username seems to be pretty close to the "standard" tcp check. With the username it does seem to send a valid startup sequence. But in both case, the connection is terminated abruptly and not properly close or it seems.

The solution might be to use [the generic TCP check](http://www.haproxy.com/doc/aloha/7.0/haproxy/healthchecks.html#checking-any-service) to open and close the connection properly but that kind of defy the whole pgsql-check purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I made such a configuration with the generic TCP check.  I can actually confirm that it's also receiving the same error in the logs.

You can find a python script + example configuration in my github repo https://github.com/gplv2/haproxy-postgresql

Even though I do send a proper hex close, I still get this in the logs:

> LOG:  could not receive data
>   from client: Connection reset by peer

Afaik, I send a proper close, I've analysed this with wireshark multiple times to see what exactly a close sends to a PG database:

```
# write: terminate session
tcp-check send-binary 58                       # Termination packet
tcp-check send-binary 00000004                 # packet length: 4 (no body)
```

This is the hex dump of a quit (command line client test)

> 00000000  58 00 00 00 04                                   X....

Fact that the standard psql-check in haproxy as well as a custom made generic one seems to yield the same results is quite interesting.  When I find the solution I will share it.

EDIT: adding source of psql protocol information:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/protocol-message-formats.html

afaik, I implemented the close exactly as documented to no avail.